# Computing Gröbner basis elements of some constant degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I'm wondering if there is any way or any special set of ideals such that there is an efficient way to compute elements of degree at most $d$ in a Gröbner basis for that ideal.

If you have any paper or hint I appreciate it.

Comment: This may be the opposite of what you are looking for but have you checked out some of the worst case behavior: http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/summary/Bardet2002.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For fixed $d$, you can do it in polynomial time. More precisely, Proposition 24.1 of *Algorithmes efficaces en calcul formel* by Bostan, Chyzak, Giusti, Lebreton, Lecerf, Salvy, Schost available [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/AECF/) says

> Given homogeneous polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_s$ in $k[X_0,\dots,X_n]$ and an integer $d$, there is an algorithm that computes the elements of degree at most $d$ of a Groebner basis of $I = (f_1,\dots,f_s)$ in time
> $$O\left(sd\binom{n+d}{d}^\omega\right)$$ where $2\le \omega \le 3$ is a matrix multiplication exponent.

Comment: Sorry for the French reference. I'm sure there exists a reference in English, but I don't know one on top of my head.